# Firebase can't get data after login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the new version of Firebase 3.0.2.

Data can be passed through firebase to different clients when they are not logged in but once log in the logged in user can't get new data or send data.

Here is my logging in code..

```
var login = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    //sign in with firebase
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {

        //get the user
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if(user) {
            console.log('user logged in');
        } else {
            console.log('user not logged in');
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        //handle error codes
    });
};
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with this error but also after log in I get the warning...

```
failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being with Firebase itself. I contacted Firebase support and apparently it was an issue with converting the old Firebase project to the new Firebase console. Apparently they had too many people importing their projects sense the new Firebase just came out. They reverted my project back to the old console and then I imported it again. Then everything worked.